# Why is INSERT adding extra empty row below each query in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysqli

My code:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

$n = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['n']);
$m = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['m']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO wishform (n,m) VALUES ('$n','$m');";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
     echo "Your ID is created successfully!";
} else {
     echo "Error!";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

In Table:

```
    308 Name1   Messege1
    309     
    310 Name2   Messege2
    311     
    312 Name3   Messege3
    313
```

Comment: it seems, empty lines are added by another code

Comment: Are the columns n and m set to not null and it is always better to check and perform an insert if the values aren't empty unless there is an explicit need for that

Comment: @harry n and m set to not null. And n and m are set  required* in form submission.

Comment: To add to what @splash58 said; it could be this code, but perhaps it gets called twice, once with an empty $_REQUEST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is, you are not checking whether the data is submitted or not.
Say for example, you have written this code in your PHP file as it is, without checking whether the user has submitted any data and that `$_REQUEST['n']` and `$_REQUEST['m']` are not empty!

So if you are not checking whether the data is submitted or not, probably you are running that piece of code each time when the page is executed, and inserts empty data to the databse!

Here's a simple idea to get you started:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    //-- get the data from $_POST array (since we are expecting the data submitted via POST method, otherwise use $_GET array)
    //-- we are trimming any extra spaces
    $n = trim( $_POST['n'] );
    $m = trim( $_POST['m'] );

    if( ! empty( $n ) AND ! empty( $m ) )
    {
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

        $n = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $n);
        $m = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $m);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO wishform (n,m) VALUES ('$n','$m');";

        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
             echo "Your ID is created successfully!";
        } else {
             echo "Error!";
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
    else
        echo 'No data submitted!';

}
```